# RelativeLayout.LayoutParams won't set the width properly android

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

So, I am trying to dynamically text box size by doing the following:

```
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setStyle(Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(2);
    paint.setTextSize(numTextSize);
    Rect textBounds = new Rect();
    paint.getTextBounds("00", 0, "00".length(), textBounds);
    Resources r = context.getResources();

    float width = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, textBounds.width(), r.getDisplayMetrics());
    float height = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, textBounds.height(), r.getDisplayMetrics());
    setViewSize(2 * (int) width, 2 * (int) height);

private void setViewSize(int width, int height)
{
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width, height);

    rlp.addRule(CENTER_VERTICAL);
    rlp.addRule(RIGHT_OF, SEPARATOR_ID);

    numView.setLayoutParams(rlp);
    numView.setPageWidth(width);
    numView.setPageHeight(height);
}
```

This works well with smaller phones such as, nexus 4 and nexus S, everything is in the text box shown [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kA0u447xeTfj2Waf-88b3d5DhcK1vnXg/view?usp=sharing). but when it comes to bigger phones such as nexus 6P, then text is off centered, shown [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aT4fBwjJrIgkfpLJoxxmK1mC-5RY3_aQ/view?usp=sharing).

In order to center it, I was playing around with values manually and tried to change the text box width to be a little wider by doing `new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(500, height);`. when I ran the code on nexus 6P, the width did not get any bigger, but when I set the width to 100, then the width shrink. When I ran it on nexus 4 or S, the width changed both with 500 and 100.

I tried to change the width and height of the xml code and that does not do anything to the actually text box at all. Following is the xml code:

```
<com.android.DigView
        android:id="@+id/digView"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/anaView" />
```

Question 1, in nexus 6P, why did the width of the text box layout did not change when I tried to increase it?
Question 2, what would be a better way to set this text box layout design so that it will display properly on both the smaller phones and bigger phones?